# WebDriver.getWindowHandle() method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium learning. WebDriver.getWindowHandle() [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandle%28%29) is not very clear to me and the example is not working as given in the book, so I thought of confirming the value returned by this method.

1) Let's say I am on page PAGE1. So getWindowHandle() should return handle to PAGE1. (Correct)

2) Now from this page, I go to PAGE2 (by hyperlink and opening a new window). My book says now getWindowHandle() should return handle to PAGE2. **However** my program still returns handle to PAGE1.

Selenium v2.43

Reproducible on Firefox and Chrome both.

**Question: What is the exact value that getWindowHandle() should return?**

```
WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
wd.get("file://D:/Projects/Selenium/Startup/web/ch3/switch_main.html");

String h1 = wd.getWindowHandle();// original handle
System.out.println("First handle = " + h1);

WebElement clickhere = wd.findElement(By.id("clickhere"));
clickhere.click();//moved to a new child page<

String h2 = wd.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Second handle = " + h2);// this handle is not different than h1
```

Answer (score 5):

`getWindowHandle()` will get the handle of the page the webDriver is currently controlling.  This handle is a unique identifier for the web page.  This is different every time you open a page even if it is the same URL.

`getWindowHandles()` (don't forget the 's') will give you all the handles for all the pages that the web driver understands are open.  Note that when you put these in a list they are listed in the order that they have been opened.

You can use `SwitchTo().Window("handle")` to switch to the window you desire.

You can use `SwitchTo().Window("mywindowID")`, if you know the window ID.

`SwitchTo().Window("")` will always go back to the base/main window.

`SwitchTo().Frame("popupFrame")` will get to the Popup that came from the window the webdriver is currently controlling.

Comment: This just needs Sizik's answer in addition, to be a very good answer. Sizik is able to address a probably very common misconception of this method, which is probably the reason for the OP's question in the first place. Plus one to both of you, for giving a very good answer combined.

Comment: @Chuck Brown - Per the [WebDriver spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-window-handles): "The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary." You should edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the link opens a new window you should have a new window handle in the `WebDriver`. You can loop current window handles with [getWindowHandles](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandles()).

See this example from http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/twist/13.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html

```
  String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
  WebDriver popup = null;
  Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
  while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
    String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
    popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    if (popup.getTitle().equals("Google") {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. I had already considered this way of getting correct window handle. However it is my strong opinion, and I must say, this is a not good API design. Consider that I am testing a big size web application and I open lots of windows from one another; in such cases, it can be a quite big effort in terms of memory and processor to get the right window handle.

Comment: @Ketan, I completely agree. Thanks for asking this question. I would expect this method to return the handle which was currently in focus, or just opened, but now I know it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the new window, the `WebDriver` doesn't automatically switch to it. You need to use the `switchTo()` method to switch to the new window, either using the name of the new window, or its handle (which you can get with `getWindowHandles()` and searching for the one that's not the current window).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code for my project

```
String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();

public static void switchingToNewTabUsingid(WebDriver driver,WebDriverWait wait,String id,String oldTab)
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
        driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();
        ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
    }
```

//Perfrom Opeartion here on switched tab

```
public static void comingBackToOldTab(WebDriver driver,String oldTab)
    {
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
    }
```

Comment: While this answer might provide information on how toswitch focus on tabs, it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium 2.53.1 using firefox 47.0.1 as the WebDriver in Java: You need to open the separate windows/browsers in it's own driver. I have having the same problem. No matter how many windows or tabs I opened, "driver.getWindowHandles()" would only return one handle so it was impossible to switch between tabs. I found Chrome worked way better for me.

Once I started using Chrome 51.0, I could get all handles. The following code show how to access multiple drivers and multiple tabs within each driver.

```
// INITIALIZE TWO DRIVERS (THESE REPRESENT SEPARATE CHROME WINDOWS/BROWSERS)
driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
driver2 = new ChromeDriver();

// LOOP TO OPEN AS MANY TABS AS YOU WISH
for(int i = 0; i < TAB_NUMBER; i++) {
   driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
   // SLEEP FOR SPLIT SECOND TO ALLOW DRIVER TIME TO OPEN TAB
   Thread.sleep(100);

 // STORE TAB HANDLES IN ARRAY LIST FOR EASY ACCESS
 ArrayList tabs1 = new ArrayList<String> (driver1.getWindowHandles());

 // REPEAT FOR THE SECOND DRIVER (SECOND CHROME BROWSER WINDOW)

 // LOOP TO OPEN AS MANY TABS AS YOU WISH
 for(int i = 0; i < TAB_NUMBER; i++) {
    driver2.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
    // SLEEP FOR SPLIT SECOND TO ALLOW DRIVER TIME TO OPEN TAB
    Thread.sleep(100);

 // STORE TAB HANDLES IN ARRAY LIST FOR EASY ACCESS
 ArrayList tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver2.getWindowHandles());

 // NOW PERFORM DESIRED TASKS WITH FIRST BROWSER IN ANY TAB
 for(int ii = 0; ii <= TAB_NUMBER; ii++) {
    driver2.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(ii));
    // LOGIC FOR THAT DRIVER'S CURRENT TAB
 }

 // PERFORM DESIRED TASKS WITH SECOND BROWSER IN ANY TAB
 for(int ii = 0; ii <= TAB_NUMBER; ii++) {
    drvier2.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(ii));
    // LOGIC FOR THAT DRIVER'S CURRENT TAB
 }
```

Hopefully that gives you a good idea of how to manipulate multiple tabs in multiple browser windows.