# Handle Window Pop Up in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am working with Selenium, now there is a condition:

when I hit a button in my webpage a window pop up opens up.

Now I have to click a radio button (one out of two, it will work even if we send a TAB ) and then click an OK button. I searched in the net and got to know about "`driver.getWindowHandle()`".

But I don't have any idea dealing with the newly opened window popup. 
Need help in this.

Comment: Switch to that window handle by `driver.switchTo().window("handle");` where `handle` is you get by `driver.getWindowHandle();`. Proceed there after.After you hit 'ok' then `driver.switchTo.defaultContent();`

Comment: I did get that , but just want to know how what the code would be to click OK on the Window Pop up. I am new to JAVA too, so i am confused about this!

Answer (score 1):

For switching purpose u can use enhanced for loop:

```
for (String winHandle : objDriver.getWindowHandles()) {
    objDriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

So it will switch the control from one driver window to child windows.

To interact with elements on the window try to find element with whatever tool u r using and perform the required action **after switching to the window**.

To return back to parent window you can use the same loop or use:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer in this post and also read the comments to help you understand the difference between getWindowHandle() and getWindowHandles()

[Java: focus is not on pop-window during window handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009634/java-focus-is-not-on-pop-window-during-window-handling/29012060?noredirect=1#comment46273487_29012060)

Comment: @Nitin - You cannot get the handle of the popup simply using `driver.getWindowHandle()`.

Answer (score 0):

We handled this situation using AutoItX - https://www.autoitscript.com/site/ in our Windows/IE C# project:

```
AutoItX3 autoIt = new AutoItX3();
var handle = autoIt.WinWaitActive("[window title]", "", 20);
Assert.IsTrue(handle != 0", string.Format("Was not able to find: {0}", [window title]);
autoIt.Send("{ESCAPE}"); // tab may work as well for selection
```

The pop up was a Windows window, and not part of IE, therefore the WebDriver didn't know about it.
Hope this helps.