# Element on a webpage overlay could not be accessed by locators

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a Webpage which gets initiated when clicked on a link . The webpage that gets opened shows an overlay screen which makes the background blur and inactive while the foreground active. However i am unable to locate any element on that overlay(foreground) through locators e.t.c. 
I tried locating elements on that overlay but the background area borders only get selected through FirePath and firebug with no overlay screen sign present in the embedded HTML code.

Below is the DOM structure for the same, which highlights the background page but does not highlights elements on the overlay foreground window.

```
 <table id="WebPart_twp146520052" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="TopazWebPartManager1_twp146520052">
<div class="masterWrapper">
<script type="text/javascript"> AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','100%','height','100%','src','/MyViewRetirement','quality','high','pluginspage','https://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','/MyViewRetirement','allowFullScreen','true', 'id','MyViewRetirement' );  </script>
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" pluginspage="https://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Versi[enter image description here][1]on=ShockwaveFlash" quality="high" src="/MyViewRetirement.swf"/>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Could any one please me on this..

Comment: Add the code that you have tried to select the elements on the overlay, please.

Comment: String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        
    }
    str_ImageSrc=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TopazWebPartManager1_twp146520052']/div/embed")).getAttribute("src");
         if(str_ImageSrc.contains(".swf"))         {
  System.out.println("Flash media recognised, hence closing the window");
linkresult13.add("Fail");    

    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to loop through WindowHandles with the for loop.  Is there only two windows handles?  Cause if there are 3 and the one you are looking for is #2, when it finishes the for loop it will have switched to #3 before you grab the attribute.  Have you tried seeing how many WindowHandles there are by dumping them into a string array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
{ 
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();

    if (bodyText.contains("Topa‌​zWebPartManager1_twp‌​146520052")) 
    {
        String str_ImageSrc = driver.findElement(By.id("Topa‌​zWebPartManager1_twp‌​146520052")).getAttribute("s‌​rc");

        if (str_ImageSrc.contains(".swf"))
        {
            System.out.println("Flash media recognised, hence closing the window"); 
            linkresult13.add("Fail"); 
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that works for you.  If it doesn't, try debugging it.  Java is not my native language.

Basically this will pull the body text, look for the ID name, if it matches it'll grab the element you are looking for by ID and then see if it contains ".swf".

You might also want to look into a while and an iterator as posted here:  [WebDriver.getWindowHandle() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871042/webdriver-getwindowhandle-method)