# What is the return type of driver.findelement /driver.getwindowhandles()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the return type of `driver.findelement` 
and what is the return type of `driver.getwindowhandles()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871042/webdriver-getwindowhandle-method

Comment: You didn't add a tag for the language you are asking about. The API documentation covers this... have you looked at it? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

### findElement()

[findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method finds the first *WebElement* using the given method. So it returns a [WebElement](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

An Example :

```
WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn']"));
```

### getwindowhandles()

[getwindowhandles()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandles--) method returns a [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) of window handles which can be iterated over all open windows through the *WebDriver* instance by passing them to [switchTo()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) function.

An Example :

```
Set<String> mySet= driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# FindElement() returns a WebElement, which is the representation of an element on a page:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

WindowHandles() returns a string representation of the window handle of the current driver:

```
foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles) {
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
}
```

This [link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) saved me lots of time when I worked in selenium years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<webelement> lt = driver.findElements(By.locator);

Set<String> set= driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Comment: Please don't just drop a blob of code in as an answer. Give it some context. Tell us briefly why you think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

driver.findelement returns WebElement
driver.getwindowhandles returns Set of Windows

Answer (score 0):

findelement returns the object of the first matching element of the specified locator. So, it's return type is an object.

findelements's return type is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Signature of findElement methid is as below.

```
WebElement findElement(By by)
```

So it should return reference of WebElement Interface.